# Choosing subsets of a set such that the subsets satisfy a global constraint

Tags: combinatorics

We have a set of items I = {i_1, i_2, ..., i_n}.  Each of these items has what we call a *p* value, which is some real number.  We want to choose a subset of I, call it I', of size m (for some m with 1 <= m <= n) such that the average of the *p* values of the items in I' falls within some specified range, [p_l, p_u].  (For example, we might require an average *p* value between 0.70 and 0.74.)  Moreover, we want to do this efficiently.

We hope to do this in O(n) time, but any polynomial time algorithm is good enough.  We certainly do not want to just try every possible subset of I of size m and then check whether it satisfies the average p-value constraint.

Finally, we will be doing this repeatedly and we want the subsets chosen to be a uniformly random distribution over all the possible such subsets.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: A polynomial time algorithm for this seems unlikely. This problem is likely equivalent to the general *Constrained Subset Selection Problem*, which is NP. If your input values are closely clustered around some pivot, and have a normal distribution, you may be able to use a backtracking algorithm to select a subset that meets the requirements. However, ensuring you get a uniform random distribution over all members of l will be challenging. You may have better luck asking for help on [mathoverflow.com](http://www.mathoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tend to think the problem is intractable also.

I might ask on mathoverflow.com, but so far I've found Stack Overflow to be much more helpful even with theoretical questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subset and its sum, if you scale the sum by |subset+1|/|subset|, each new element you add contributes linearly to the sum. This thus seems extremely similar to the subset-sum problem (NP-complete), where the goal is to find all subset which sum to 0, albeit here we wish the sum to be close to 0. For example, if you have a large set where one element is roughly in the acceptable p-range, if you make the sketchy assumption that that element doesn't matter, suddenly it is practically equivalent... assuming you have a large number of positive and negative p-values, and the problem is not constructed by an adversary. If this is the case, you could use one of the two approximating solutions given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem , make the equality "fuzzy", and just tack on a "reserved" element with 0.7<p<0.74 to the set.

Of course the efficiency you can eek out of your solution is *incredibly* dependent on the way p-values are generated (the "distribution" thereof).